# Move Solr data from v4 to v7

Tags: solr, import, export, solr4

I have a solr cluster running solr v4.3 I want to export all the data and import it into a new solr v7.1 cluster.

What options do I have to export/import the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

options are:

1. if you have ALL your fields stored, you can try several things:

   - use DIH in Solr7 to index all data from a [SolrEntityProcessor](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#SolrEntityProcessor)
   - write some scripts/code to export all data (in batches, using cursorMark if available in 4.3 or doing the cursor yourself with a fq on some field) in csv, and index it into Solr7
   - similarly, write some java/Solrj code that does the same thing
2. if you don't have all fields stored, then the only way is upgrading to Solr 6 first, then to 7 (by going through the upgrade process, but this does not reindex the data, which is highly recommended)

All this, assuming you don't have the original data to reindex, if you have it, it is a no brainer: reindex off it.